# Pacman orphan packages

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

I was under the impression that "orphaned" packages listed by `pacman` are packages that have been installed as a dependency but are no longer needed.

But looking at the orphaned results I can see packages like `Inkscape` and `ttf` fonts which clearly don't fit that description. So now I'm not sure if I should be deleting them or not. Can someone explain what "orphaned" packages are?

List of orphaned packages in pamac:

[image: List of orphaned packages in pamac]

Same list from `pacman -Qdtq`:

[image: list of orphaned packages with pacman]

Comment: Pamac is not your package manager; please paste a list of orphans that pacman prints, and the command you used to produce it.

Comment: @jasonwryan Doesn't pamac use pacman as a back-end? I added the pacman list as well.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, paste the *actual text*.

Comment: It isn't passive aggressive, it is [how the site works](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)... And it isn't more informative at all. If you posted the text and the command you used, it would actually be helpful *and* relevant.

Comment: @Rtsne42, nobody here is going to be suspicious where you got your text from. They're trying to help you so they're going to trust you're actually helping yourself by copying the right text. If you really are going to screw your question by pasting something that wasn't part of your query no-one can help you.

Answer (score 3):

pamac defines orphans as packages that were installed as a requirement of another package but are not (optionally) required by any other package anymore ([source](https://github.com/manjaro/pamac/blob/master/src/daemon.vala#L677-L682)).

Not having looked at all packages in your list, but at least [inkscape](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/inkscape/) and [ttf-courier-prime](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ttf-courier-prime/), [ttf-heuristica](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ttf-heuristica/) and [ttf-impallari-cantora](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ttf-impallari-cantora/) are packages that can be required by some other ones, which suggests you had some other package that needed them installed once upon a time and deleted those.

Comment: That makes things uncertain I suppose, since I don't know what is an actual orphaned package and what is useful software that accidentally got tagged as orphaned. I like to keep my system clean but now I'm not sure what can be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

`man pacman` explains the orphan concept:

> -d, --deps
>              Restrict or filter output to packages installed as dependencies.
>
> This option can be combined with -t for listing real orphans -
>              *packages that were installed as dependencies but are no longer required by any installed package*.

All of the packages pacman printed look like they were at one time dependencies of another package, so can safely be removed. If you are unsure, you can run `pacman -Qi $package` on a package to see what it provides or is required by.

Comment: Thanks for  your comment, but based on `pacman -Qdt` I have many softwares that doesn't look like dependencies. For instance "pinta" is among them. Running `pacman -Qi pinta` shows `Required By     : None` and `Optional For    : None` but `Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package`. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

As a convenience, I have this in `~/.bash_aliases` that lets me clean up orphaned packages easily:

```bsh
# Remove orphaned packages.
# Needs single quotes, otherwise the newlines that "pacman -Qqdt" outputs
# cause trouble.
# The parentheses create a subshell meaning "set -x" that prints the executed
# Bash commands is unset when the subshell exits at the end of the command.
# Arguments to "pacman -Q":
#    -d restrict output to packages installed as dependencies
#    -t list packages that are no longer required by any installed package
#    -q suppress version numbers of packages (this would confuse pacman -R)
alias cleanup_packages='(set -x; sudo pacman -Rs $(pacman -Qdtq))'
```

Comment: handy, but doesn't answer the question